# Angular 2 Directive with ngModel and ngControl

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I want to write a Angular 2 Directive, which should have the following behavior:

1. Must be usable with and without a wrapping `<form [ngFormModel]="form">`
2. Should use `[(ngModel)]` for data binding
3. Use an `Observer` internally, which updates the `ngModel` 250ms after the last user input happened
4. When using a wrapping `<form [ngFormModel]="form">` it should be possible to listen for `form.valueChanges` (which of course should fire 250ms after the last user input)

---

I've written the following Directive for testing:

```
import {Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from 'angular2/core'
import {NgModel} from 'angular2/common'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'

@Directive({
    selector: '[queryDirective]'
})
export class QueryDirective {
    constructor(public model:NgModel) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.model.control.valueChanges
            .debounceTime(250)
            .subscribe(val => this.model.control.updateValue(val,{emitEvent:true}));
    }
}
```

It works when using **no** `ngControl`. It then says that no provider for `NgModel` can be found.

```
<form [ngFormModel]="form">
    <input queryDirective ngControl="..." type="text" [(ngModel)]="...">
</form>
```

But when I use `NgControl` on the constructor the `this.model.control.updateValue` method won't update the `ngModel`.

---

What am I doing wrong? Or does anyone have some example code that is working?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now got it working!

Here's my directive:

```
import {Directive, Renderer, ElementRef, forwardRef, Provider} from 'angular2/core'
import {NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, DefaultValueAccessor} from 'angular2/common'
import {CONST_EXPR} from 'angular2/src/facade/lang'
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'

const PROVIDER = CONST_EXPR(new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => QueryDirective), multi: true}));

@Directive({
    selector: '[queryDirective]',
    bindings: [PROVIDER]
})
export class QueryDirective extends DefaultValueAccessor {
    constructor(_renderer: Renderer, private el: ElementRef) {
        super(_renderer, el);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        Observable.fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'keyup')
            .map(val => this.el.nativeElement.value)
            .debounceTime(this.timeout)
            o.subscribe(this.onChange);
    }
}
```

I have no clue what that `bindings` and `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` stuff does, but it works!